# Older iPhones doesn't get proper PWA icon

Tags: ios, angular, iphone, progressive-web-apps

We are currently adding PWA feature to our Angular web app, but have some issues on iOS devices. While iPhones above iPhone X getting proper icon, some older phones have issues.

For example, on iPhone 7 Plus (iOS 13.3, Safari 13, build 4.6.1.04), proper icon appears only on second install. On the first one - it's displayed as a page screenshot.
On iPhone 6s (iOS 13.3.1) - proper icon doesn't appear even after reinstall. Only page screen.

Beside manifest, I've also added icons in index.html .

```
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/touch-icon-ipad.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" href="/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
```

Size of the first one - is 192x192.

Is it some kind of system issue on iOS, or I'm missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you would need the following sizes for earlier devices.

57×57px
72×72px
76×76px
114×114px
120×120px
144×144px

As of iOS 11.1, Safari starts to look in the manifest for the icons.

I think you can add a single 180x180 in the head of your page  and it will be automatically scaled but the above list will cover each device individually.

Good luck.